# Is it possible to use an expandablelistview as a dropdownview for a spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, expandablelistview

I have a 2d array of strings. I would like to use a spinner to allow users to select values from the 2nd lvl of the array but I would like to display the selection options in a expandablelistview using the values of the 1st lvl of the array as category headers.

Is this possible, can someone point me in the right direction of how this should be implemented ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot directly use an `ExpandableListView` for the `Spinner` popup, any more than you can directly use a `ListView` for the `Spinner` popup. It is what it is, and that is defined by the `Spinner` class.

Options include:

- Subclassing `Spinner` and overriding whatever drives the popup dialog
- Copying `Spinner` into your project and replacing whatever drives the popup dialog (if overriding will not work due to method visibility, etc.)
- Don't use a `Spinner`, and instead use a `Button` plus an `AlertDialog` containing an `ExpandableListView`, or something like that

In principle, you could override `getDropDownView()` in your `SpinnerAdapter` (e.g., `ArrayAdapter`). However, there is no concept of the drop-down view being disabled, and I assume you would want your category headers to be non-selectable. If, however, selecting a category is acceptable, this approach would be simplest.