# Advice/Help : Best way to implement Categories inside a Spinner (like Microsoft Windows' Menu on their OS)

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, spinner, android-spinner

I am using a custom adapter to populate a spinner with custom item.
The layout is a single dropdown list.

As title say, i would like to have items (that represents categories) in my spinner.
Like : Italy, France, Germany. (example).
Each item should open on it's right then a second spinner with cities in it (like a nested spinner).
Like : Rome, Firenze, Milano.
I want it to look and behave like Microsoft Windows bottom Menu (XP, Vista, 7).

Is it possible ?
Can anyone help on this ?

*Oh...and my spinner is inside a drawer `DrawerLayout` that inflates a `ListView`...just to add some complexity ;)*

---

**CustomSpinnerAdapter class**

```
public class CustomSpinnerAdapterCity extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerItem> {

    Context context;
    int layoutResID;
    List<SpinnerItem> spinnerData;
    protected LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public CustomSpinnerAdapterCity(Context context, int layoutResourceID, int textViewResourceId, List<SpinnerItem> spinnerDataList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, textViewResourceId, spinnerDataList);
        this.context=context;
        this.layoutResID=layoutResourceID;
        this.spinnerData=spinnerDataList;
    }

    public CustomSpinnerAdapterCity(Context context, int layoutResourceID, List<SpinnerItem> spinnerDataList) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, spinnerDataList);

        this.context=context;
        this.layoutResID=layoutResourceID;
        this.spinnerData=spinnerDataList;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row=convertView;
        SpinnerHolder holder;

        SpinnerItem mSpinnerItem =spinnerData.get(position);

            if(row==null)
            {
                LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

                row=inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
                holder=new SpinnerHolder();

                holder.current_city=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.current_city);
                holder.current_city_description=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.current_city_description);

                row.setTag(holder);
            }
            else
            {
                holder=(SpinnerHolder)row.getTag();
            }
            if(mSpinnerItem.getCurrentChoice()!=null)
            {
                holder.current_city.setText(mSpinnerItem.getCurrentChoice());
                holder.current_city_description.setText(mSpinnerItem.getCurrentChoiceDescription());
            }

       return row;
    }

    public int getPosition(SpinnerItem s) {
    return super.getPosition(s);        //return position of the last value
    }


@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return super.getCount()-3; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
    }
    public int getCountCertifiedonly() {
        return super.getCount()-2; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
    }
    public int getCountVIPonly() {
        return super.getCount()-1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
    }
public int getCountCityNone() {
    return super.getCount()-1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
}


private static class SpinnerHolder
    {
        TextView  current_city,current_city_description;

    }

}
```

**SpinnerItem class**

```
public class SpinnerItem implements Item{

    String choice;
    String choice_description;
    Boolean isSection = false;

    public SpinnerItem(String choice, String choice_description, Boolean isSection) {
        super();

        this.choice=choice;
        this.choice_description=choice_description;
        this.isSection=isSection;
    }

public String getCurrentChoiceDescription() {
    return choice_description;
}

public void setCurrentChoiceDescription(String choice_description) {
    this.choice_description = choice_description;
}

public String getCurrentChoice() {
    return choice;
}

public void setCurrentChoice(String choice) {
    this.choice = choice;
}

@Override
public boolean isSection() {
    return isSection;
}
```

}

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3865596/794088  might help

Answer (score 0):

You don't need listview for that , you can utilize naviation drawer and menu combination.

see details

https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-design-support-library-b7cda56d2c32